# Specify template to be display in a 'render'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im trying to use,the 'render' in ember.js, what I want to do is specify which template content will be render:

```
<div>
{{render "content"}}
</div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="template1"> 
 content 1
<script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="template2"> 
 content 2
<script>


App.ContentView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: validateSomething() ? 'template1' : 'template2',
});
```

That's what I have but is not working, is it possible make what I'm trying? Some other ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `templateName: validateSomething() ? 'template1' : 'template2'` will work. Why not use the Handlebars `{{#if}}{{/if}}` helper to determine what to render (within your content template)?

Update: This could be more what you are after:

```
<div>
{{render "content"}}
</div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="content"> 
  {{#if condition}}
     {{view App.Template1View thisBinding="this"}}
  {{else}}
     {{view App.Template1View thisBinding="this"}}
  {{/if}}
<script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="template1"> 
 content 1
<script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="template2"> 
 content 2
<script>
```

I haven't been able to test this yet, but it should be enough to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to do something more complicated, but yes, using the if statement worked.

Comment: You could also have 2 different views and within your `{{render}}` template decide which one to render using the `{{view}}` helper.